# Cравнение значения с NA в условном операторе

Tags: r

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в `data.frame` нужно заменить все `NA`, на значения, которые стоят выше них в столбцах.

Для этого я пишу следующий цикл:

```
for (i in 1:length(data[1])) {
  for (j in 1:length(data[,1])) {
    if (data[i,j] == NA) {
      data[i,j]<-data[i,j-1]
    }
  }
}
```

Другими словами, я воздействую сначала поочередно на каждую строчку в столбце, и в случае, если значение ячейки `[i, j]` равно NA, я заменяю его значением этого же столбца, только выше.

В теории все логично, но R выдает ошибку, что

```
Error in if (data[i, j] == NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Хотя вроде бы я все верно написал.

Comment: Если переводить ошибку, не хватает TRUE или FALSE значения.

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу: что планируется делать в случае, когда в первой строке значение `NA`, а также если несколько `NA` идёт подряд?

Comment: Понял, что немного запутался, и никаких проблем при подряд идущих значениях нет. Тем не менее, первая часть вопроса всё же актуальна.

Comment: Мне вот даже исправленное решение не очень нравится эстетически.
Двойной цикл все-таки???
А нельзя ли эту задачу решить в более векторном виде???
Ifelse поможет, но никак не соображу как в этом случае сослаться на предыдущую строку...

Comment: @YuryArrow Мне тоже не нравится решение через двойной цикл, но векторно у меня получилось решить только если нет двух `NA` подряд, что не очень интересно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Редактирование дата-фрейма, содержащего NA](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432807/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-na)

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что любое сравнение с `NA` возвращает `NA`.
Соответственно, условие `smth == NA` всегда вернёт `NA`.

Условный оператор `if` не может обработать подобное значение, поэтому возникает указанная ошибка.

Для правильного сравнения с `NA` используйте функцию `is.na`, как указал @YuryArrow.

---

Ещё заметил, что описание задачи отличается от того, что вы реализовали. У вас есть ещё несколько ошибок:

1. Если `data` является `data.frame`, то `data[1]` также будет являться `data.frame`, следовательно `length(data[1])` будет всегда возвращать 1, так как возвращается число столбцов, а `data[1]` -- это первый столбец. Вместо этого, для большей ясности, лучше использовать функцию `ncol`. Для получения числа строк в `data.frame` можно использовать парную функцию `nrow`.
2. У вас присваивается значение не из того же столбца, а из строки левее из-за перепутанных индексирующих переменных.

Исправленное решение может выглядеть, например, так:

```
for (col in 1:ncol(data)){
  for (row in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (is.na(data[row,col])) {
      data[row,col] <- data[row-1,col]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, что так можно на NA сравнивать.
Попробуйте лучше так:

```
if (is.na(data[i,j])) {
  data[i,j] <- data[i,j-1]
}
```

**update:** @TimofeyBondarev
Вот оно самое красивое (внешне, по крайней мере) решение:

```
library(zoo)
data <- data.frame(
   x=c(1,  2,NA, 4,NA,NA), 
   y=c(11,NA,13,NA,15,NA),
   z=c(NA,'Fil','Tor',NA,NA,NA)
)
na.locf(data)
```

Comment: Отличное решение, но думаю, что стоит добавить немного информации из документации к этой функции о том, что она может удалять строки из данных.

Answer (score 2):

Решение без циклов:

```
data <- data.frame(
    x=c(1,  2,NA, 4,NA,NA), 
    y=c(11,NA,13,NA,15,NA),
    z=c(NA,'Fil','Tor',NA,NA,NA)
)
# Находим индексы пропущенных значений.
nas <- which(is.na(data), arr.ind=TRUE)
for_replace <- nas
# Ищем индексы значений, на которые нужно заменить NA
for_replace[, 1] <- for_replace[, 1]-1
data[nas] <- data[for_replace]
```

Если первое значение является NA или есть несколько NA подряд, то замена произведена не будет (естественно), но и ошибки не возникнет; будет лишь предупреждение.
Решение с пакетом *zoo* лучше в данном случае, но менее универсально.