# Редактирование дата-фрейма, содержащего NA

Tags: циклы, r

Проблема заключается в следующем:

Имеется дата-фрейм, в котором необходимо заменить `NA` на значение, содержащееся в предыдущей строчке.

В случае с вектором данная проблема решается прогонкой цикла по вектору, однако для редактирования дата-фрейма данный способ не подходит.

Comment: Дубль вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431634/c%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-na-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5